# Update query with inner join - use updated column value to the another column of same table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to update one column valur from the another updated column in same table with same SQL query. There are 3 tables joined in update query as below:

```
UPDATE table1
     INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.pid
     INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.id = table2.cid
SET 
    table1.col1 = "1+2+3",
    table1.col2 = table1.col1 + 5
WHERE 
    table1.id = 5
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If `col1 = 10`, `col2 = 20` and `new_value = 30`, after the update what is your expected output? Are you expecting, `col1 = 30`, `col2 = 10` or something else?

Comment: No, I am expecting col1 and col2 both should be updated as 30 to the new_value.

Comment: If you want the same value in both columns, then `SET table1.col1 = "1+2+3", table1.col2 = "1+2+3"` will work, right?

Comment: :D nope I wanna do some other calc on base of the first column value. so i need value from column only.. In hurry I forgot to put it.. edited question

Comment: syntax to achieve this result will depend on the database (MySQL/MariaDB vs SQL Server vs Oracle vs Teradata vs ...) add the appropriate tag `[mysql]`,`[sql-server]`, or if you can't figure that out, at least include information in the question. (I recommend that we *first* write a SELECT statement that exercises the expressions, and returns the rows we want to update along with the new values to be assigned; once we have that, it's a lot easier to wrangle into an UPDATE.

Comment: I need it with MySQL

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment, if you want the `new_value` to be updated in `Col1` and `Col2` columns, you can use the following update block

```
UPDATE table1
     INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.pid
     INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.id = table2.cid
SET 
    table1.col1 = new_value,
    table1.col2 = new_value
WHERE 
    table1.id = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the table in the SET statement as the fields are ambiguous.

```
UPDATE table1
  INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.pid
  INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.id = table2.cid
----- (Option1 - Shifting values in a single table) -----  
SET  
  table1.col1 = table1.col2,
  table1.col2 = table1.col3,
  table1.col3 = table1.col4
----- (Option2 - Assigning values across tables) -----
SET
  table1.col1 = table2.col2,
  table2.col1 = table3.col2,
  table3.col1 = table1.col2
----- (Option2 - Updating values across tables) -----
SET
  table1.col1 = table1.col2 + 1,
  table2.col1 = table2.col2 - 1,
  table3.col1 = table3.col2 + table3.col1
WHERE
  table1.id = 5

NB: SET commands are done in the order listed so may you need to swop the two lines around in the set to get what you want.

SET
  table1.col2 = table1.col1 + 5,
  table1.col1 = "1+2+3"
```

Comment: Edited question please check query again .... I want to update the column of same table from another updated column.. for eg.. value of table1.col1 should be table1.col2

Comment: So you wish to shift a value in a table and then update the shifted with a new value from a different table?

Comment: Nope please read the question carefully. I want to update same table column value on bases of another columns value. its posiible in simple update query without join but not working with inner join.